# How can I use Ubuntu to fix my Windows OS

Tags: 12.10, windows

My Windows Vista OS is not booting up, but Ubuntu is working fine for me. I do not have an Ubuntu Live CD but I do have a USB...however I do not know how to create a Ubuntu Live USB. I want to revive my Windows OS so if there is anyway I can clone the hard drive or fix the OS so it will boot properly then I would be very happy. I really hope someone can help me here.

Comment: Depending on the **errors** that Vista would throw when it fails to boot you may need to use a Windows disk to do boot and OS repair.

Answer (score 1):

(In Ubuntu)

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)
```

Then open Boot-Repair. Click 'Recomended Repair'.

Then wait for it to complete. You should be able boot into Windows Vista.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: in the existing Ubuntu, I used this and in advanced part, I changed  MBR to load only windows Vista. So, before destroying the system, I could solve boot problem and now am going to remove the ubuntu partition. THANKS